# Display multiple polygons on Google Maps and toggle visibility of each polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display multiple polygons (with the co ordinates either given by the user or pre-defined) on Google Maps and to toggle the visibility of each polygon. I wrote the code to display multiple polygons by manually entering all the longitudes and latitudes values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multi Polygon</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 700px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var map;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8500,-87.9645),
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.7508, -88.1535)});
   marker.setMap(map);
   // Construct the polygon.
  var multiPolygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
         new google.maps.LatLng(41.769007157585534,-88.20167541503906), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.76081263047197,-88.12236785888672), 
    new google.maps.LatLng( 41.717517926019624,-88.19429397583008)],
    strokeColor: '#ff987b',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#ff987b',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    name: 'Polygon 1', 
        map: map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon1, 'click', showArrays);

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.8661, -88.1070)});
   marker1.setMap(map);
  // Construct the polygon.
 var multiPolygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.88336502279732,-88.09249877929688), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.88157575821145,-88.12957763671875), 
    new google.maps.LatLng( 41.84271080015277,-88.12408447265625),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 41.841431946284025,-88.08425903320312)],
    strokeColor: '#ff987b',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#ff987b',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 2',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon2, 'click', showArrays);

   var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.9103, -88.0717)});
   marker2.setMap(map);

  var multiPolygon3 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.96051129429776,-88.12957763671875), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.93906275484857, -88.00048828125), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.884387437207835, -88.02314758300781),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.879275201550634, -88.07395935058594),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.948766559468574, -88.11172485351562)],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 3',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon3, 'click', showArrays);

  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.79179268262892, -88.07601928710938)});
   marker3.setMap(map);

  var multiPolygon4 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.80203073088394, -88.09730529785156), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.801006999656636, -88.07533264160156), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.74313962010849, -88.05301666259766)],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 4',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon4, 'click', showArrays);

  var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.9231, -87.7093)});
   marker4.setMap(map);

  var multiPolygon5 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.901254912872794, -87.94418334960938), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.949277245116555, -87.92015075683594), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.93446570034958, -87.87895202636719),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.96459591213679, -87.82608032226562),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.9753167881278, -87.78968811035156),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.899721690058364, -87.83706665039062),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.937019660425264, -87.72239685058594),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.87569639323101, -87.63175964355469)],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 5',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon5, 'click', showArrays);

  var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.8050, -87.8692)});
   marker5.setMap(map);

  var multiPolygon6 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.780016905285535, -87.95448303222656), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.83171182161546, -87.96066284179688), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.83273506215261, -87.94281005859375),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.81073178596061, -87.88925170898438),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.81226714359981, -87.78282165527344),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.87723019276536, -87.77114868164062),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.782577040867636, -87.74848937988281),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.77182378456081, -87.88581848144531),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.801006999656636, -87.9290771484375)],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 6',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon6, 'click', showArrays);

  var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.7200, -87.7480)});
   marker6.setMap(map);

  var multiPolygon7 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.852173524388824, -87.62489318847656), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.70880422215806, -87.62283325195312), 
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.70829161455626, -88.0059814453125),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.74416427530836, -87.96821594238281),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.73545418490723, -87.91603088378906),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.735966575868716, -87.68051147460938),
    new google.maps.LatLng(41.840920397579936, -87.67707824707031)],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
     name: 'Polygon 7',
     map:map
  });

  // Add a listener for the click event.
  google.maps.event.addListener(multiPolygon7, 'click', showArrays);
}

/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function showArrays(event) {

  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath()
  // to return the MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var vertices = this.getPath();

  var contentString = '<b>' + this.name + '</b>';
  // '<br>' +
  //     'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
  //     '<br>';

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  // for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
  //   var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
  //   contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
  //       xy.lng();
  // }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  infoWindow.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the code is too lengthy and inefficient. How can I make my code object oriented and reduce the repetitive code? I tried using function to reduce the code but it did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Multi Polygon</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 700px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var path1 = [
  [41.769007157585534,-88.20167541503906],
  [41.76081263047197,-88.12236785888672],
  [41.717517926019624,-88.19429397583008]];

var path2 = [
  [41.88336502279732,-88.09249877929688],
  [41.88157575821145,-88.12957763671875],
  [41.84271080015277,-88.12408447265625],
  [41.841431946284025,-88.08425903320312]];

var path3 = [
  [41.96051129429776,-88.12957763671875],
  [41.93906275484857, -88.00048828125],
  [41.884387437207835, -88.02314758300781],
  [41.879275201550634, -88.07395935058594],
  [41.948766559468574, -88.11172485351562]];

var path4 = [
  [41.80203073088394, -88.09730529785156],
  [41.801006999656636, -88.07533264160156],
  [41.74313962010849, -88.05301666259766]];

var path5 = [
  [41.901254912872794, -87.94418334960938],
  [41.949277245116555, -87.92015075683594],
  [41.93446570034958, -87.87895202636719],
  [41.96459591213679, -87.82608032226562],
  [41.9753167881278, -87.78968811035156],
  [41.899721690058364, -87.83706665039062],
  [41.937019660425264, -87.72239685058594],
  [41.87569639323101, -87.63175964355469]];

var path6 = [
  [41.780016905285535, -87.95448303222656],
  [41.83171182161546, -87.96066284179688],
  [41.83273506215261, -87.94281005859375],
  [41.81073178596061, -87.88925170898438],
  [41.81226714359981, -87.78282165527344],
  [41.87723019276536, -87.77114868164062],
  [41.782577040867636, -87.74848937988281],
  [41.77182378456081, -87.88581848144531],
  [41.801006999656636, -87.9290771484375]];

var path7 = [
  [41.852173524388824, -87.62489318847656],
  [41.70880422215806, -87.62283325195312],
  [41.70829161455626, -88.0059814453125],
  [41.74416427530836, -87.96821594238281],
  [41.73545418490723, -87.91603088378906],
  [41.735966575868716, -87.68051147460938],
  [41.840920397579936, -87.67707824707031]];

function mapToLatLng(source, index, array) {
  return new google.maps.LatLng(source[0], source[1])
}

function toLatLng(array) {
  return array.map(mapToLatLng);
}

function newPolyOptions(path) {
  return new google.maps.Polygon({
    path:path,
    strokeColor:"FF0000",
    strokeOpacity:0,
    strokeWeight:3,
    fillColor:"#94C11F",
    fillOpacity:0.5,
    clickable:false
  });
}

function newPolyLine(polyOptions) {
  var polyLine = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  polyLine.setMap(map);
  return polyLine;
}

var poly1 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path1)));
var poly2 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path2)));
var poly3 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path3)));
var poly4 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path4)));
var poly5 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path5)));
var poly6 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path6)));
var poly7 = newPolyLine(newPolyOptions(toLatLng(path7)));

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I want to toggle the visibility of each polygon using checkbox. I tried doing that and the code works perfectly fine for only 1 polygon. However, if I apply for multiple polygons, it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas{
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0px; 
        height: 590px;} 
        </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        // Move map declaration
        var map;

        function toggleLayer(toggleLayer,id)
        {
            if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) {
                toggleLayer.setMap(map);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleLayer.setMap(null);
            }
        }

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8500,-87.9645),
              //  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            };

            // Set map    
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(41.7508, -88.1535)});
            marker.setMap(map);

           poly1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(41.769007157585534,-88.20167541503906), 
                new google.maps.LatLng(41.76081263047197,-88.12236785888672), 
                new google.maps.LatLng( 41.717517926019624,-88.19429397583008)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                fillColor: '#ff987b',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                name: 'Polygon 2',
            map:map
            });

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="togglepoly1" type="checkbox" checked="yes" onClick="toggleLayer(poly1,'togglepoly1')" /> Polygon 1
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use checkboxes to toggle polygons, you can set a user-defined properties when you creating a new polygon. For example:

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: data.location,
        fillColor: '#6c757d',
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        clickable: true,
        markers: [],
        treeMap: new Map(),
        name: data.name,
        manager: data.manager,
        id: data.id,
        density_color: '#6c757d'
    });
```

The last 6 properties are user-defined so that you can add ID property for each polygon and toggle them using `setMap(Null)`.

Ps: You should put all your polygons in an array for better manipulating.